# PHP - SQL optimization min/max too slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

I'm having some problems with a query that finds the next ID of an orders with certain filters on it - Like it should be from a specific city, etc.

Currently it's used for a function, where it'll either spit out the previous or the next ID based on the current order. So it can either be min(id) or max(id), where max(id) is obviously faster, since it has to go through less rows.

The query is working just fine, but it's rather slow, since it's going through 123953 rows to find the ID. Is there any way I could optimize this?

Function example:

```
SELECT $minmax(orders.orders_id) AS new_id FROM orders LEFT JOIN orders_status ON orders.orders_status = orders_status.orders_status_id $where_join WHERE orders_status.language_id = '$languages_id' AND orders.orders_date_finished != '1900-01-01 00:00:00' AND orders.orders_id $largersmaller $ordersid $where;
```

Live example

```
SELECT min(orders.orders_id)
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN orders_status ON orders.orders_status = orders_status.orders_status_id
WHERE orders_status.language_id = '4' 
  AND orders.orders_date_finished != '1900-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND orders.orders_id < 4868771 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Have an index on orders.orders_id and remove the joins to orders_products and products. You don't use these two tables anyway. The where clause turns your left join to orders_status into an inner join, btw.

Comment: is date_finished a key? And how can that date be 1900-01-01? Unless you are working on some historical data, would NULL not be a more logic value (as I suppose that is what 1900 is about)

Comment: @IvoP It's a -real- legacy system and full of flaws - Hence why it's not totally logical or optimal

Comment: @fancyPants Updated the question to match current query and function

Comment: is the column orders_status in the table orders a key? and is language_id in orders_status? and orders_date_finished?

Comment: @IvoP They are, yes, indexes atleast

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is superfluous. The `GROUP BY` aggregate function [`MIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) requires the presence of the `GROUP BY` clause to work properly. When the query doesn't contain the `GROUP BY` clause, SQL implicitly assume `GROUP BY 1` and that means it creates one group that includes all the rows that match the `WHERE` conditions. Exactly one row is generated using the data contained in each group.

Comment: try `SELECT orders.orders_id` combined with `ORDER BY orders.order_id ASC` and keep the `LIMIT 1` as well

Comment: and loose the "LEFT": the line asking the language_id to be 4, implies it is an inner join. Which is faster than a left join

Comment: @IvoP That's the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so concluding:

```
SELECT orders.orders_id
FROM orders 
JOIN orders_status ON orders.orders_status = orders_status.orders_status_id
WHERE orders_status.language_id = '4' 
  AND orders.orders_date_finished != '1900-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND orders.orders_id < 4868771 
ORDER BY orders.orders_id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Extra:

to get the MAX value, use DESC where ASC is now.

And looking at your question: be sure to escape the values like $language_id etcetera. I suppose they could come from some html form?
(or use prepared statements)